# How to show a view programmatically

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

[image]

Above is my storyboard. The first view is hooked up to ViewController, and the second isn't connected to anything. I know how to show the second view controller if I had a button on the first. I can click and drag from the button to the second view, creating a segue. However, this time, I have to show the second view controller programmatically inside ViewController.m. For example, in when some function myFunc is called, I want to show the second view controller. Could someone explain how I can do this?

I think I need to know the followings:

1. How to reference the second view controller in ViewController.m
2. How to open the second view controller

Thank you!

**UPDATE:**

```
//setSelectedDate is myFunc. It lives inside myView.m, which is a subview of UIView

- (void)setSelectedDate:(NSDate *)newSelectedDate; {
    NSLog(@"override worked");
    [super setSelectedDate:newSelectedDate];

    UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
    UIViewController *firstController = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"InitialViewController"];
    UIViewController *myController = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"MySecondViewController"];
    [firstController presentViewController:myController animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

I get the following warning if I do above:

Warning: Attempt to present  on  whose view is not in the window hierarchy!

and from this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11862883/whose-view-is-not-in-the-window-hierarchy) I believe it's because I am doing it in the wrong place. How can I resolve this issue?

**Update 2: I did the following: **

```
- (void)setSelectedDate:(NSDate *)newSelectedDate; {
    [super setSelectedDate:newSelectedDate];

    UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];

    UIViewController *firstController = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"InitialViewController"];

    [firstController performSegueWithIdentifier:@"GoToSecondViewController" sender:firstController];
```

The warning is gone, but the view controller is still not showing. Is it because I am calling this inside a View instead of a ViewController?

Comment: Is your second view a view or a view controller?

Comment: It's a ViewController. I realized I have to use performSegueWithIdentifier, but I am not sure how to get the "identifier" reference.

Comment: You may then want to consider editing your question to be less ambiguous to help out any potential answerers :)

Comment: Apropos your updates, you should call `performSegueWithIdentifier:sender:` from a UIViewController. The one you are calling it from there still is not being shown; it's a separate instance of your InitialViewController.

Comment: @ahruss I see. Thank you! How do I get the reference for the firstViewController instead of instantiating it?

Answer (score 2):

You could do one of the following:

Create a segue in your storyboard by dragging from the firstViewController to the second one. Then give that segue a name (fill the Identifier field, under Attributes inspector on the right pane in Interface Builder). Let's say "GoToSecondViewController".

In your `myFunc` method (or function), call

```
[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"GoToSecondViewController" sender:nil];
```

OR

Give your second viewcontroller a storyboard ID. From the interface builder, click on your second viewcontroller. On the right pane under "Identity inspector" fill in the Storyboard ID field. Let's say "MySecondViewController".

In your `myFunc` method (or function) do the following:

```
UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]]; // or whatever your storyboard is called
UIViewController *myController = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"MySecondViewController"];
[self presentViewController:myController animated:YES completion:nil]; // present it or push it if you have a navigation controller
```

Comment: Thank you! I thought it would work but the view isn't showing, and I get the following warning: `Warning: Attempt to present <UIViewController: 0x7fbc13cbd420> on <ViewController: 0x7fbc13c866a0> whose view is not in the window hierarchy!`

Answer (score 1):

To avoid tightly coupling these components, here's how I'd do it.

In `myView.h`, add a delegate protocol to which your `InitialViewController` will conform, and a property of that type to the `myView` class:

```
@class myView;

@protocol myViewDelegate 
-(void)datePickerDidChangeValue:(myView*)view;
@end

@interface myView : UIView 
@property IBOutlet id<myViewDelegate> delegate;
// ... other members ...
@end
```

And in its implementation call that delegate method in the `setSelectedDate:` method:

```
-(void)setSelectedDate:(NSDate*)selectedDate
{ 
    _selectedDate = selectedDate;
    [self.delegate datePickerDidChangeValue:self];
}
```

Then, set the delegate property in InterfaceBuilder to be your InitialViewController. Right click on your custom view and then drag from the `delegate` outlet to your ViewController:

[image: Screenshot of Interface Builder]

Then, in InitialViewController.h, set it to conform to the myViewDelegate protocol:

```
#import "myView.h"

@interface InitialViewController : UIViewController<myViewDelegate>
// ... members ... 
@end
```

and implement that delegate method, something like this, assuming you've set up the identifiers as described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26579017/1325329):

```
-(void)datePickerDidChangeValue:(myView*)view 
{
    NSDate* theDate = view.selectedDate; // do whatever you want with this value

    UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]]; 
    UIViewController *myController = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"MySecondViewController"];
    [self presentViewController:myController animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```